# CodeIgniter's valid_email() vs PHP filter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I noticed that CodeIgniter has implemented the `valid_email()` function, in which they are using `preg_match`.

Why didn't they use PHP's filter with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter_var()` [requires PHP 5.2 or greater](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). [CodeIgniter runs on PHP 5.1.6 or greater](http://codeigniter.com/news/codeigniter_2.0_-_now_with_more_awesome/). The CodeIgniter developers can't guarantee that people will have access to the `filter_var()` function.